# Column rank of a matrix with zero block

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Consider a matrix
$$
B\equiv \begin{pmatrix}
D'D & D'F \\
0_{d\times n} & P'F
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where

- (1): $D'D$ is an $n\times n$ diagonal matrix with strictly positive elements in the diagonal
- (2): $0_{d\times n}$ is a $d\times n$ matrix of zeros
- (3): $D'F$ is an $n\times J$ matrix
- (4): $P'F$ is a $d\times J$ matrix

**Question:** is it true that $B$ has column-rank $n+J$ if and only if $P'F$ has column-rank $J$? Which properties from (1)-(4) are you using to enstablish such a result? In particular, is (2) key to claim this result?

Comment: Yes, it is true. This only requires property (2).

Comment: Does it require also (1) (i.e., $D'D$ with rank $n$)?

Comment: Sorry, that's an important point I missed. Yes, it also requires $D'D$ to have rank $n$ (i.e. full column rank). In fact, the matrix will have full column rank iff both $D'D$ and $P'F$ each have full column rank